# Upgrading 5.1 (9B176) and Xcode 4.2 Build 4C199

Tags: ios, xcode, upgrade

The version of iOS on “XXX iPod” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available.

I'm not sure what's going on.  I pressed run. It doesn't work either. I reinstalled provisioning profiles again and Xcode again. I see have same error. On the Organizer. All I see is "yellow" ball. But The prevision version 5.0 (9A334) works.

How do I fix this? Do I have to wait for new Xcode to come out?

Answer (score 3):

your device iOS is 5.1 and Xcode 4.2 only supports iOS version till 5.0.1

You will need to update Xcode to Xcode 4.3 (which supports iOS 5.1 devices) ( Note : Xcode 4.3 is only available for MAC OS X Lion)

Comment: Hi. Ive downloaded newest Version and it tells me I have document format XCode 3.2 and it works with iPad but when trying to update to XCode 4.3 there is only an "Install" button which is disabled. Why can't I update? I have LION and working developer license.